# g++ and clang++ different behaviour deducing variadic template `auto` values

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

Another "who's right between g++ and clang++?"

This time I'm convinced it's a g++ bug, but I ask for a confirm from standard gurus.

Given the following code

```
template <template <auto...> class Cnt,
          typename ... Types,
          Types ... Vals>
void foo (Cnt<Vals...>)
 { }

template <auto ...>
struct bar
 { };

int main ()
 {
   foo(bar<0, 1>{});  // compile both
   foo(bar<0, 1L>{}); // only clang++ compile; error from g++
 }
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/V6Gbgk)

clang++ (8.0.0, by example) compile and link without problem where g++ (9.2.0, by example) gives the following error compiling the second `foo()` (but not the first) call

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:16:20: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(bar<0, 1>)'
   16 |    foo(bar<0, 1L>{}); // only clang++ compile; error from g++
      |                    ^
prog.cc:6:6: note: candidate: 'template<template<auto ...<anonymous> > class Cnt, class ... Types, Types ...Vals> void foo(Cnt<Vals ...>)'
    6 | void foo (Cnt<Vals...>)
      |      ^~~
prog.cc:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:16:20: note:   mismatched types 'int' and 'long int'
   16 |    foo(bar<0, 1L>{}); // only clang++ compile; error from g++
      |                    ^
prog.cc:16:20: note:   'bar<0, 1>' is not derived from 'Cnt<Vals ...>'
```

If I understand correctly, g++ require that the `Types...` of the `Vals...` coincide where clang++ accept that the `Vals...` are of different `Types...`.

Who's right?

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by Marek R (thanks) also MSVC (v19.22) fail to compile.

But, if I understand correctly, fail also compiling the first `foo()` call with the following error

```
<source>(13): error C2672: 'foo': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(13): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void foo(Cnt<Vals...>)'
<source>(13): note: With the following template arguments:
<source>(13): note: 'Cnt=bar'
<source>(13): note: 'Types={}'
<source>(13): note: 'Vals={0, 1}'
```

**-- EDIT 2 --**

camp0 observes (thanks) that g++ compile this code until version 7.4.

A bug introduced from 8.1 or is bugged my code and g++ has corrected his code from 8.1?

Comment: `msvc` reports similar issue (I've provided [godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/V6Gbgk)). You need `laguage-lawyer`.

Comment: @MarekR - D'oh! You're right: `language lawyer` is needed. Thanks. Anyway, seeing your demo, I see that `msvc` fail also with first call.

Comment: Looks that with gcc 7.4 is working that code, Not sure if they introduce the issue on 8.1 intentionally or is a bug

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None of the three compilers is correct.

From [[temp.param]/17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#17):

> If a *template-parameter* is a *type-parameter* with an ellipsis prior to its optional *identifier* or is a *parameter-declaration* that declares a pack ([dcl.fct]), then the *template-parameter* is a template parameter pack. A template parameter pack that is a *parameter-declaration* whose type contains one or more unexpanded packs is a pack expansion. ... **A template parameter pack that is a pack expansion shall not expand a template parameter pack declared in the same *template-parameter-list***. [ Example:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> template <class... T, T... Values>              // error: Values expands template type parameter
>   struct static_array;                          // pack T within the same template parameter list
> ```
>
> — end example ]

So the code is ill-formed, even without the line `foo(bar<0, 1L>{});`.

There is already a Clang [bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24625) and a GCC [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67397).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know at all that you can't declare and expand a template pack in the same parameter list. If I understand correctly, you're citing another C++ standardization version. But I've verified with the last C++17 draft and the same phrase (and the same example) are there. Just an objection: given that the point is that  you can't declare and expand a template pack in the same parameter list, isn't bugged also g++? Take in count that g++ compile `foo(bar<0, 1>{});`. If the error is in the declaration of `foo()`, how can a compiler correctly compile every instantiation of `foo()`?

Comment: @max66 When you declare and expand a template pack for **function** both gcc and clang can compile, but msvc will not compile. When you declare **class** they all will not compile. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6_14ne)

Comment: Sorry but I'm highly confused... I'm added [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700049/g-and-clang-are-both-bugged-with-template-function-parameter-pack-expansion). It seems to me that, given the statement and the example you're found, or I misunderstand the statement, or there is a special rule for template functions or both g++ and clang++ are bugged.

Comment: @康桓瑋 - Regarding functions, what you observed seems confirmed in my new question. Anyway, I am increasingly confused.

Comment: @max66 Updated the answer. Hope it is helpful now.