# g++ and clang++ are both bugged with template function parameter pack expansion?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

This is a follows up of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689726/g-and-clang-different-behaviour-deducing-variadic-template-auto-values) where an answer point my attention to Templates [temp.param] 17.1.17 (last C++17 draft, but I suppose also preceding standardizations) where is stated that

> A template parameter pack that is a pack expansion shall not expand a parameter pack declared in the same template-parameter-list.

with an example of this limitation

> ```
> template <class... T, T... Values> // error: Values expands template type parameter
> struct static_array;               // pack T within the same template parameter list
> ```

So, if I understand correctly this rule, the following function (that I find extremely reasonable) is illegal

```
template <typename ... Types, Types ... Values>
void foo (std::integral_constant<Types, Values>...)
 { ((std::cout << Values << std::endl), ...); }
```

because the second parameter pack (`Types ... Values`) expand a parameter pack (`Types`) declared in the same template parameter lists.

Anyway, both g++ (9.2.0, by example) and clang++ (8.0.0, by example) compile the following code without problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ... Types, Types ... Values>
void foo (std::integral_constant<Types, Values>...)
 { ((std::cout << Values << std::endl), ...); }

int main()
 {
   foo(std::integral_constant<int, 0>{},
       std::integral_constant<long, 1L>{},
       std::integral_constant<long long, 2LL>{});
 }
```

So I suppose there is something I misunderstand.

Are both g++ and clang++ bugged or am I that misunderstand the standard?

Comment: For once MSVS doesn't compile.  ICC does not as well.  Looks like an extension/bug to me.

Comment: Also, did you not notice the bug report link for gcc on the top answer?

Comment: @NathanOliver - But I've compiled with "-pedantic-error"; more a bug than an extension, IMHO.

Comment: Call it what you will, you have the standard quote saying it is illegal, so it's illegal.  If they compile then it's a bug/extension.

Comment: @NathanOliver - D'Oh! - I've read it yesterday but I've forgotten. But not completely, considering I've used `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Maybe you're right. But, as Linux and open-source enthusiast, is painful to think that g++ and clang++ are bugged and msvc correct.

Comment: It happens.  C++ is a very complex language and g++ and clang have bugs that have been opened for years.  Same goes for MSVS.  They are all not 100% conformant, but they are all close, to varying degrees.  It just goes to show that open-source doesn't guarantee that things get fixed quickly.

Comment: Just to prove the point, both `constexpr` and TMP are Turing complete languages so C++ is 3 Turing complete languages all wraped together in a manner that is still mostly backwards compatible to what it was in 1998.  That offers a lot a places to get things wrong.

Comment: @NathanOliver - yes... sometimes variadic ellipsis seems to me part a morse message from my subconscious saying "sos, abandon ship, saves who can". The bad part is that I love it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's illegal, the standard is very clear.  For what it's worth, MSVC doesn't seem to accept the code (https://godbolt.org/z/DtLJg5).  This is a GCC bug and a [Clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24625).  (I didn't check old versions.)

As a workaround, you can do something like this:

```
template <typename... ICs>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<is_integral_constant<ICs>...>> foo(ICs...)
{
    ((std::cout << ICs::value << '\n'), ...);
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/-gD2h9)

Comment: When you declare `template <typename... Types, Types... Values>
void foo(std::integral_constant<Types, Values>...);` MSVC **will** accept it; But when  you declare `template <typename... Types, Types... Values>
void bar();` MSVC will not accept it. So MSVC also has this bug? see [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/FEPKpI).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Well, I think you are right ...  A diagnostic is required for an ill-formed declaration in any case

Comment: @康桓瑋 Thank you for the demo!