# GCC & Clang vs MSVC Bug while expanding template parameter pack in the same parameter clause for function templates

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, function-templates, pack-expansion

I came across the following statement in the [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#17):

> If a *template-parameter* is a *type-parameter* with an ellipsis prior to its optional *identifier* or is a *parameter-declaration* that declares a pack ([dcl.fct]), then the *template-parameter* is a template parameter pack. A template parameter pack that is a *parameter-declaration* whose type contains one or more unexpanded packs is a pack expansion. ... **A template parameter pack that is a pack expansion shall not expand a template parameter pack declared in the same *template-parameter-list***.

(end quote)

So consider the following **invalid** example:

```
template<typename... Ts, Ts... vals> struct mytuple {}; //invalid
```

The above example is **invalid because** the template type parameter pack `Ts` cannot be expanded in its own parameter list.

---

##### Are the below given examples valid/invalid?

Then i tried the same with function templates and expected the same result but to my surprise it [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/PaWKKq4n7) fine in gcc & clang but not in msvc. The example is as follows:

```
//is this valid?
template<typename... T, T... ar>
void func(){}

int main()
{   
}
```

Similarly, the below given [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ahTYnjfTo) compiles in gcc and clang but not in msvc:

```
//is this valid?
template<typename...T, int (*FUNC)(T...)>
int wrapper(T... args) { return (*FUNC)(args...) * 10; }

int main()
{  
}
```

**Which compiler is right here?** That is, does the [quoted statement temp.param#17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#17) applies to the given two examples and so they are invalidated or is the quote not applicable to the given two examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700049/g-and-clang-are-both-bugged-with-template-function-parameter-pack-expansion

Comment: The quote applies to all snippets except the last, because that expansion doesn't create a template parameter pack.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion: "Which compiler is right?" You wrote clearly-defined-as-invalid code, MSVC *correctly* throws an error while gcc and clang do not. Therefore MSVC is correct. GCC and Clang are not.

Comment: @Casey So you too think that both the snippet given in my program are invalid because of my quoted statement from the standard? My confusion came because 2 of the compilers were compiling the code without any error and i also heard(really, read) somewhere that the second snippet is valid. If you do think that msvc is right in rejecting both the code snippet and gcc/clang are wrong in not rejecting the snippets, you can add an answer saying that it is a bug in gcc and clang.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in GCC and Clang. You wrote clearly-defined-as-invalid code, MSVC correctly throws an error while gcc and clang do not. Therefore MSVC is correct. GCC and Clang are not.

As an aside, I ran the code snippets in MSVC C++20 mode and the same error was still thrown. It's been correctly handled since C++14 in MSVC and a bug in GCC and Clang for just as long.